# LakeFormation permissions returning "ALL"

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lake-formation

I noticed that LakeFormation SDK calls (both boto3 via AWS CLI, and Go via Terraform) are returning `ALL` in the list of permissions assigned to a resource.

for example:

```
    "PrincipalResourcePermissions": [
        {
            "Principal": {
                "DataLakePrincipalIdentifier": "arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNT:role/FooRole"
            },
            "Resource": {
                "Table": {
                    "CatalogId": "ACCOUNT",
                    "DatabaseName": "lf_test",
                    "Name": "foo"
                }
            },
            "Permissions": [
                "ALL",
                "DESCRIBE"
            ],
            "PermissionsWithGrantOption": []
        }
```

Yet, I cannot delete this "ALL" permission. Attempting to revoke with either AWS CLI or Terraform results in error:

```
An error occurred (InvalidInputException) when calling the RevokePermissions operation: No permissions revoked. Grantee does not have:[ALL]
```

What's going on here, and how do I fix it other than special-casing to ignore "ALL"?

Comment: Did you solve this issue? How are you trying to revoke the permission?

Comment: I think it had something to do with IAMAllowedPrincipals and maybe Terraform isn't accounting for that?  But I haven't looked at in a while.